# Find $E[XY]$ of joint hypergeometric by conditioning on $Y$

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory

> An urn contains $N = 30$ balls. There are $10$ balls of color X, and
>   $8$ balls of color Y, and let random variables $X, Y$ denote the count
>   of each, respectively. Also assume $n = 12$ balls are selected without
>   replacement. Find $E[XY]$ by conditioning on $Y$, i.e. first find
>   $E[X| Y = y]$.

We have a hypergeometric distribution here, but with two random variables. I was thinking it would be easier to approach this problem by reasoning $P(X=x|Y=y)$ directly instead of computing $\frac{P(X = x, Y = y)}{P(Y=y)}$.

First, for $E[X]$ and $P(Y=y)$ I have 
$$E[X] = \sum_{x=0}^{10} x \frac{\binom{10}{x}\binom{30-10}{12-x}}{\binom{30}{12}} = 4$$ 
$$P(Y=y)=  \frac{\binom{8}{y}\binom{30-8}{12-y}}{\binom{30}{12}}$$

Next to find $P(X=x|Y=y)$, I have

$$
P(X=x | Y=y) =  \frac{\binom{10}{x} \binom{30-(10+y)}{12-(x+y)}}{ \binom{(30-y)}{12-y}}
$$

There must be a mistake, however, since when I try to compute and verify $E[X] = E[E[X|Y]]$, I have

$$
\sum_{y=0}^{8} E[X|Y=y] P(Y=y) = \sum_{y=0}^8 \sum_{x=0}^{10}x P(X=x|Y=y)P(Y=y) \approx. 3.27
$$

So in order to solve the problem of finding $E[XY]$, I'm stuck here at finding $P(X=x|Y=y)$. Please help me find my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $Y = y$, you have taken out $12-y$ other non-Y balls from an urn with $22$ non-Y balls, of which $10$ are colour X and $12$ are neither X nor Y.  The probability that $x$ of these are $X$ is then $$ P(X=x|Y=y) = \dfrac{{10 \choose x} {12 \choose 12 - y - x}}{{22 \choose 12 - y}}$$

Comment: I see now. All $8$ of the Ys have to be excluded from the possibilities, not just $y$ as I had thought, since otherwise  would allow counting possibilities of more Ys than $Y = y$.